# Linux mint wifi device not on rfkill list

Tags: wifi

I just installed Linux Mint 16 Cinnamon. But I could not get the wifi device. I googled and found `rfkill list` but only the bluetooth appears on the list.

When I turn of the hardware switch even the bluetooth disappears from the list.

Comment: It's probably not showing because it hasn't recognised the device. Add the output of `lspci` or `lsusb` to your question (depending on whether it's an USB device or PCI, or if unsure add both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answering my own question!**

Found the solution from comptb.cects.com/bcm4311-mint16-nowireless-nointernet, click on it for details!

Here is a solution that worked form me!
Steps:

1. Download b43-fwcutter for your architecture (bottom of page) from http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/b43-fwcutter. In this case, b43-fwcutter_013-2_amd64.deb was used, but an older version or a 32-bit version probably would have worked as well.
2. Download the source file from http://mirror2.openwrt.org/sources/. In this case, broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5.tar.bz2 was used. Scroll down the page to locate the broadcom files entries.
3. Transfer the files to your user directory on the Linux Mint PC and double-click the b43-fwcutter file to install it. Ignore any warnings about the version being out-of-date.
4. Run the following commands to extract and write the firmware to /lib/firmware. Ignore any warnings.

   tar xfvj broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5.tar.bz2

   sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-4.150.10.5/driver/wl_apsta_mimo.o
5. Reboot the PC.
6. The wireless should now work. If so, look for and install any updated B43 wireless firmware/fwcutter/drivers using the Synaptic Package Manager. Do not use B43 legacy.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me on Linux Mint "Rebecca" 64bit, running Cinnamon:

1. Open the DVD / USB with the Linux install.
2. Go to /pool/main/e/eglibc.
3. Install both packages. (*libc6-dev* & *libc-dev-bin*)
4. Go to /pool/main/b/bcmwl.
5. Install package. (*bcmwl-kernel-source*).

**Note**: If you don't find the packages there, search them elsewhere in /pool. (updates might change paths)